# Source for Lubavitch Siddur Legend

Tags: sources-mekorot, chabad, agada-stories-legends, chassidic-rebbe

If you take a look in the old print of the Siddur Tehilas Hashem on page 13, you will notice a strange looking vav in the word "yetzur" (as in "yetzur nivra" from the tefillah of Adon Olam).

I have been told by a few people that this strange looking vav is actually an elongated yud, and that the Rebbe turned the yud into a vav with his pen to make the text read "yetzur" (as per the nusach of the Alter Rebbe) as opposed to "yetzir" (as other nusachos render it).

Could anyone verify this story? I'm not necessarily looking for a source (because I doubt it's been written down) but maybe someone has heard this legend as well? I have added a picture so that you understand what I mean:

[image]

[image]

Here's a normal vav for comparison:

[image]

As you can see, the vav does look a bit strange compared to the other vavs which are on the same page.

However, I see a few problems with this legend:

How did the Rebbe erase the chirik which would have been beneath the tzadik?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72141/discussion-on-question-by-ezra-source-for-lubavitch-siddur-legend).